# Multiple form with same name array

Tags: php, input, request

I have 2 forms like this:

Form No.1:

```
<input type="text" name='name[]' placeholder = 'Input your name' >
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your first vehicle'>
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your second vehicle'>
....
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your xxx vehicle'>
```

Form No.2:

```
<input type="text" name='name[]' placeholder = 'Input your name' >
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your first vehicle'>
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your second vehicle'>
....
<input type="text" name='vehicles[]' placeholder = 'Input your xxx vehicle'>
```

The vehicle input is dynamic input added by JavaScript, so how identify the vehicle owned by correct person? I have retrieved data, but I don't know how to split the vehicle by each person.

Comment: you need to give different name in each input field to hold all input values.

Comment: so each form have different name ?

Comment: all the input are in single form or multiple form ?

Comment: like vehicles1[],vehicles2[],vehicles3[] so on..

Comment: single form , and the amount of form is dynamic too , so there's maybe append form for person 3 and until person n

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo so how i know how many the person filled?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a solution simply for your vehicles fields, hopefully you will be able to modify this code to suit your needs.

Add a number at the end of the name when you create it using JavaScript, i.e:

```
var counter = 0;
function addInput() {
    document.getElementById("form").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<input type=\"text\" name=\"vehicles"+counter+"\" placeholder=\"Input vehicle #"+counter+"\">");
    counter++;
}
```

Then, in PHP, you can simply get a list of all items sent via `$_POST`:

```
$vehicles = array_keys($_POST); //Get all of the $_POST values
for ($i=0;$i<count($vehicles);$i++) { //Loop through all $_POST values
    if (strpos($vehicles[$i], "vehicles")!==false) { //If the name contains "vehicles"
        $value = $_POST[$vehicles[$i]]; //Get the value of the field
        echo $i . " " . $value . "<br>"; //Echo it out as a test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create not inputs with a `name[]` and `vehicles[]` names for each appended form, but wrap inputs in user(or any else name you want) array and do something like `users[].name[]` and `users[].vehicles[]`.(i dont sure about right syntax but the thing is wrap it)